# Order of short circuit evaluation and prefix increment operators

Tags: java, boolean, logic

When evaluating a Boolean expression in java, I find myself a bit bewildered by short circuit evaluation and pre-fix increment operators.  Consider the following:

```
    int e=20;
    int f=25;
    if(++e>21 || ++e>21 && f>30){

        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
    System.out.println(e);
```

I understand that if ++e were greater than 21, the rest of the IF statement would skip over (due to short circuit eval).  But in this case, it doesn't, as the first part is not true, so we move on to the AND statement.  At this point, is e still 20?  Or during the short circuit eval, did it go up to 21?

Well, I am assuming at this point, we evaluate the AND statement (as we normally do before OR), we add 1 to e, which I assume becomes 21 now?  It is false, and therefore the entire AND statement is false.

Do we, at this point, go BACK and do the OR statement?  Since it comes after AND?  Shouldn't e be pumped up to 22 now? And since it's an OR statement, it should come out to TRUE OR FALSE, which should be TRUE, and "Hi" should appear on the screen. But it doesn't.

Weirdly, the value for e is 22 when the code finishes.  22 is the value we needed for the IF statement to be true, but the condition inside didn't run.

I am extremely confused.

Comment: You should not compress your code as much as possible. Your goal is to make a clear to understand code, not decreasing number of lines as much as possible. This type of coding is an example of bad programming practice.

Comment: But to answer your question, preincrement/predecrement operators do their operation before the expression is executed, postincrement/postdecrement do their operation after the expression has executed.

Comment: @madcobra as much as I agree, this *appears* to be a simple educational exercise, not real code. At least, I *hope* it's not! But I second this; please don't write code with side effects inside expressions in real code!

Answer (score 7):

Let's unwind what short-circuiting actually is!

```
int e=20;
int f=25;
if((++e>21) || (++e>21 && f>30)){

    System.out.println("Hi");
}
System.out.println(e);
```

So, if that left hand side of the `or` condition evaluates to true, we don't need to do anything more, so let's be more explicit about that:

```
int e=20;
int f=25;
if (++e > 21)
{
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
// the or becomes an else if, if the first condition fails then we check the second
else if (++e>21 && f>30)
{
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
System.out.println(e);
```

Now, let's be more explicit about when that first increment happens:

```
int e=20;
int f=25;
e += 1;
if (e > 21) // e = 21, 21 is not > 21
{
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
// We need to test this condition, as you've said
// e is still 21
else if (++e>21 && f>30)
{
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
System.out.println(e);
```

Again, let's unwind what `and` means in terms of short-circuiting

```
int e=20;
int f=25;
e += 1;
if (e > 21) // e = 21, 21 is not > 21
{
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
// We need to test this condition, as you've said
// e is still 21
else if (++e > 21) // the and becomes a nested if, first the left must be true before we test the right
{
    if (f > 30)
    {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
System.out.println(e);
```

And again, let's be explicit about that increment!

```
int e=20;
int f=25;
e += 1;
if (e > 21) // e = 21, 21 is not > 21
{
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
// We need to test this condition, as you've said
// e is still 21
else 
{
    e += 1;
    if (e > 21) // e is now 22, this condition succeeds
    {
        if (f > 30) // f is not >30, this condition fails!
        {
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }
    }
    // e is still 22
}
// e is still 22
System.out.println(e);
```

Hopefully this makes it all clear!

EDIT: Actually, having re-read your question a couple of times, it appears you are getting confused with the precedence of the logical operators. You seem to think that the `and` should execute before the `or` right? presumably because `and` has the higher precedence. All that means, however, is that the implicit brackets go round the `and` first like so;

`p || q && r == p || (q && r)`

You should be able to see that in this form, the outside `or` must be evaluated first, before the `and` is. We always evaluate left to right!

Comment: If we evaluated left to right, then why do operators have precedence?  Isn't the entire point of precedence is to allow once to go first?

Comment: @mattjenkins No, the point of precedence is to ensure *grouping* of operations. For instance if * and + were the same precedence then `3 + 8 * 4` would naturally bracket as `(3+8)*4` since they are left associative operators. This is clearly incorrect. By making * a higher precedence we force the bracketing to happen around `8*4` instead. It's all to do with parsing the expressions, not evaluating them.

Comment: @MattJenkins The same applies to the boolean expressions, we wanted `p || q && r` to ensure the `q` and `r` belong to the `&&`. That implies `&&` has the higher precedence. I should note that when I say that evaluation must happen from left to right, this is only true when side-effects are involved (i.e. your `++`). Otherwise you could evaluate however you liked. The point is the the bracketing of the operations were correct. Short-circuiting semantics on the other hand must work left to right, otherwise things would get very strange, very fast.

Comment: @MattJenkins Consider for example, a common use of short-circuiting; `p != null && p.x == 1`, this ensures that we can't get a null pointer from evaluating `p.x`, if `p` were `null` then the second part of the expression cannot be reached. In non-shortcircuiting or unordered semantics for evaluation then `p.x` could be executed before the null-check or even alongside and clearly we didn't want that. Now consider `p == null || p.x != 0 && p.x != 1`. The && binds tighter, but it would be a disaster if it were executed first!

Comment: @MattJenkins Though, to add to that last example, what if we didn't have precedence? then the expression would parse as `(p == null || p.x != 0) && p.x != 1`. If we execute this expression then short-circuiting guards against the null-dereference in the ||, but then a null value may reach the `p.x != 1` check... and boom.